# Ada: prefix issue in getting last element in an array

Tags: arrays, ada

I am experimenting with my first Ada program (Ada 2012) and running into some difficulties. I am getting input from the user and storing this into a number of unbounded strings. Then I am passing these unbounded strings into a procedure where I extract the last element of each of the unbounded strings and add that to the character array. I read that arrays need to be instantiated as types, but when I do so, I run into errors, so I instantiated without the type reference.

The problem comes in with

```
   last: Character := c0.Last;
```

I am getting an "invalid prefix in selected component "c0"" error.

Below is the code so far:

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO, Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO, Ada.Strings.Unbounded, Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Text_IO;

    procedure game is

      card0: Unbounded_String;
      card1: Unbounded_String;
      card2: Unbounded_String;
      card3: Unbounded_String;
      card4: Unbounded_String;

      cardNumArray: array (1..5) of Integer;
      suiteArray: array (1..5) of Character;

   procedure setUpData(c0, c1, c2, c3, c4: in Unbounded_String) is
     last_c0: Character := c0.Last;
    begin

      suiteArray := (last_c0, 'S', 'S', 'H', 'S');

    end setUpData;

    begin 

      Put_Line ("Enter your card details:\n");
      Put_Line ("Enter card 1, e.g. ""AH:"" ");
      Get_Line(card0);
      Put_Line ("Enter card 2, e.g. ""KH:"" ");
      Get_Line(card1);
      Put_Line ("Enter card 3, e.g. ""QH:"" ");
      Get_Line(card2);
      Put_Line ("Enter card 4, e.g. ""10H:"" ");
      Get_Line(card3);
      Put_Line ("Enter card 5, e.g. ""JH:"" ");
      Get_Line(card4);

      setUpData(card0, card1, card2, card3, card4);

    end game;
```

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to write `c0.Last`, when `c0` is an `Unbounded_String`?

Comment: Have you browsed section A.4.5 in the Language Reference Manual?  It may help you.

Comment: As an occasional card player I feel obliged to tell you that cards have "suits", not "suites".

Comment: Duly noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
last_c0 : Character := element (c0, length (c0));
```

is likely to solve your problem.